# too few arguments to function (char*)

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I am working at an school project and I am programming the game Hangman.
It is not allowed to use object-orientated programming.
So I just thought about functions (*clever boy* :D).

Now I have this functions:

```
void LoadHangman();
int PlayHangman(char searchedWord[20], char platzhalter[8]);
int FindLengthFromString(char searchedWord[]);
int CheckIfLostOrWon();
```

In the function LoadHangman, I initiate a Word which should get find from the user later.
Also I initiated a char  arry called placeholder who just got '_'

```
char searchedWord[20] = {'H','a','n','g','m','a','n',0};
char placeholder[8] = {'_','_','_','_','_','_','_'};
```

Now I want to transfer(sorry for that bad english) it to the function PlayHangman( ... )

```
PlayHangman(searchedWord,placeholder);
```

Now, I initiate the function PlayHangman( ... )

```
int PlayHangman(char searchedWord[20],char placeholder[8])
```

And the compiler just says:
At the beginning { from the function:

```
error: too few arguments to function 'int PlayHangman(char*, char*)'
```

At the end } from this function:

```
error: at this point in file
```

I am angry about myself, that I am to stupid, to solve this problem (it seems to be an easy problem......)

ps: I am reading an C++ Book...but...I...just....dont...get...it.....

Hole Code, for all this programming gods:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

///Funktionsdeklarationen
void LoadHangman();
int PlayHangman(char searchedWord[20], char placeholder[8]);
int FindLengthFromString(char searchedWord[]);
int CheckIfLostOrWon();

int main()
{
    ///Deklarationen
    int won_lost = CheckIfLostOrWon();

    ///Programm
    LoadHangman();
    switch(won_lost)
    {
        case 1: cout << "\n\nGlückwunsch! Sie haben gewonnen!\n"; return 0;break;
        case -1: cout << "\n\nSchade. Sie haben leider nicht gewonnen.\n";return 0; break;
        default : break;
    }
}

void LoadHangman()
{
    ///Deklarationen
    char searchedWord[20] = {'H','a','n','g','m','a','n',0};
    char placeholder[8] = {'_','_','_','_','_','_','_'};
    int lengthFromString;

    ///Programm
    lengthFromString = FindLengthFromString(searchedWord);
    cout << "Gesuchtes Wort: ";

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthFromString; i++) {cout << " " << placeholder[i] << endl;}

    cout << "Bitte geben Sie einen Buchstaben ein: ";

    PlayHangman(searchedWord,placeholder);
}

int PlayHangman(char searchedWord[20],char placeholder[8])
{
    ///Deklarationen   / Initialisation
    int uebereinstimmung;
    int fehlerAnzahl = 0;
    char character;
    int lengthFromString = FindLengthFromString(searchedWord);

    uebereinstimmung = 0;

    ///Programm
    cin >> character;

    for(int i = 0; i < lengthFromString; i++)                                                           //Für die Länge des Strings
    {
        if(character != searchedWord[i]) {uebereinstimmung -= 1;}                                       //Übereinstimmung verringern
        else if(character == searchedWord[i]) {placeholder[i] = character; uebereinstimmung = 100;};     //Platzhalter mit Buchstaben füllen und übereinstimmung auf 100 setzen
    }

    if(uebereinstimmung < 0) {fehlerAnzahl++;};

    return fehlerAnzahl;

}

int CheckIfLostOrWon(char searchedWord[],char placeholder[])
{
    ///Deklarationen
    int lengthFromString = FindLengthFromString(searchedWord);
    int fehlerAnzahl = PlayHangman();

    ///Programm
    int won = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < lengthFromString; i++)
    {
        if(placeholder[i] == searchedWord[i]) {won++;};
    }
    if(won == lengthFromString) {return 1;};
    switch(fehlerAnzahl)
    {
        case 8: return -1;
    }
}

int FindLengthFromString(char searchedWord[])
{
    ///Deklarationen
    int lengthFromString = 0;
    int i = 0;

    ///Programm
    while(searchedWord[i] != 0) {lengthFromString++; i++;}
    return lengthFromString;
}
```

Sorry, the comments are in german.

Already tried to use (pointer)

```
int PlayHangman(char* searchedWord,char* placeholder)
```

not working aswell.

[Result for others]

I corrected my stupidness:

int fehlerAnzahl = PlayHangman(searchedWord,placeholder);

Thanks all.

Comment: `CheckIfLostOrWon` needs to `return` a value in every possible path (currently if `fehlerAnzahl` is not `8` then it will fall off the end, which causes undefined behaviour)

Comment: your line `int fehlerAnzahl = PlayHangman();` is wrong. You call your function without parameters. No parameter is less then 2 :-)

Comment: Why do you have an empty stamement `;` at few places after control blocks ? Also, `CheckIfLostOrWon` doesn't always return a value. `warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PlayHangman` function requires 2 arguments

However when you try to call it you don't pass it any arguments:

```
int fehlerAnzahl = PlayHangman();
```

You will need to send the correct parameters to `PlayHangman` to fix this, the compiler gives you a hint that this is the problem with the error message when it says:

```
error: too few arguments to function 'int PlayHangman(char*, char*)'
```

Always compile with all warnings enabled and pay attention to any warnings and errors as this is a good way to use the compiler to help you find and fix your problems. Also if this were a real c++ project I would strongly suggest that you use `std::sting` to store your strings, it will make things much easier for you.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt see it (*dump*), we are not alloweded to use "finished" functions, but cout and cin;

Answer (score 1):

See full compiler error message:

```
k.cc: In function 'int CheckIfLostOrWon(char*, char*)':
k.cc:73:36: error: too few arguments to function 'int PlayHangman(char*, char*)'

     int fehlerAnzahl = PlayHangman();
                                    ^
```

This tells you exactly where to look. You call the `PlayHangman` function with no arguments in that place.  If your compiler is not indicating where the error was ...  that'd be a strange compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You have one `PlayHangman()` at line 73 with no arguments.  As you mentioned, your PLayHangman() function takes two arguments, and you *always* have to pass two arguments.